# Why is this requests get not working with this url

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

If i run this Python code my program just hangs up. (I don`t get any error.)

```py
import requests
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/docs/master/site/en/tutorials/generative/dcgan.ipynb"
r = requests.get(url)
```

But this works perfectly fine as expected.

```py
import requests
url = "https://stackoverflow.com" 
r = requests.get(url)
```

Using `curl` to get the github file worked also fine.

```bash
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/docs/master/site/en/tutorials/generative/dcgan.ipynb
```

So can you reproduce my problem, did i overlocked something trivial or is it just something with my python environment?

```bash
python3 --version
Python 3.8.10

pip show requests
Name: requests
Version: 2.22.0
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: http://python-requests.org
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

Comment: The example you've given works perfectly fine for me in a terminal~

Comment: That is funny, thank for trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be getting stuck in redirects. You can overcome this by setting `allow_redirects=False`. The following code works for me:

```
import requests
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/docs/master/site/en/tutorials/generative/dcgan.ipynb"

try: 
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False, timeout=10)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as err: 
    print(err)

print(r.json())
```

Comment: That solved it for me. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly for me. If it 'hangs' a poor connection can cause it. What you can do is provide a `timeout` argument, which will wait that many seconds, and if it does not receive a response from the server will continue executing code.

```
import requests
url = "https://stackoverflow.com" 
r = requests.get(url, timeout=2)
```

Comment: Thank, that helps to to encircle the problem. But a poor connection can not be the problem since curl downloaded it in a time not worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. However if you still have problems with `requests`, you could even use `urllib.request`

For example:

```
import urllib.request
import requests

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/docs/master/site/en/tutorials/generative/dcgan.ipynb"

r = requests.get(url)
print(r)
u = urllib.request.urlopen(url).getcode()
print(u)
```

They have the same output:

```
<Response [200]>
200
```